# Change matrix elements in one matrix, given statements in two other matrices, in python

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I have two 1D matrices A and B, containing `NaN` values in some random places. I want to add these matrices element wise `(C[i] = A[i] + B[i])` and take the mean of the element sums. This works well and efficiently in the code below:

```
import numpy as np
# Create some fake matrices
A = np.arange(0,10,0.5)
B = 10.0*np.arange(0,10,0.5)

# Replace some random elements in A and B with NaN 
A[15] = np.nan
A[16] = np.nan
A[17] = np.nan
A[18] = np.nan
B[1] = np.nan
B[2] = np.nan
B[17] = np.nan
B[18] = np.nan

# Sum over A and B, element wise, and take the mean of the sums
C = 0.5 * ( np.where(np.isnan(A), B, A + np.nan_to_num(B)) )
```

But, if one of `A[i]` and `B[i]` contains `NaN` and the other one doesn't, I don't want to take the mean of the sum, but rather keep the value of the matrix with a value that is not `NaN`. This I have not been able to solve.

In other words (given A and B) eventually I want C to be:

```
A
array([ 0., 0.5, 1., 1.5, 2., 2.5, 3., 3.5, 4., 4.5, 
        5., 5.5, 6., 6.5, 7., nan, nan, nan, nan, 9.5])
B
array([ 0., nan, nan, 15., 20., 25., 30., 35., 40., 45.,
        50., 55., 60., 65., 70., 75., 80., nan, nan, 95.])
# What I eventually want C to be:
C
array([  0., 0.5, 1. , 8.25, 11., 13.75, 16.5, 19.25, 22., 24.75, 
         27.5, 30.25, 33., 35.75, 38.5, 75., 80., nan, nan, 52.25])
```

Does anyone have any (efficient) suggestions how I can do this? (For example, I would like to avoid time consuming loops if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumPy's [`nanmean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html) generates warnings when both numbers are `np.nan`, but it gives the result you want:

```
C = np.nanmean([A, B], axis=0)
```

Comment: Thank you! Elegant solution!

Comment: @kirerik No worries, feel free to upvote or accept if it solved your problem!